# Does Fritz 17 have extra features compared to othe Chessbase offerings?

Tags: chessbase, fritz

For me, the strength of the chess engine is not that important as today almost all of the top engines are beyond human level. I want to use a chess program for training and analysis of my games.

If I understand correctly, Chessbase publishes several chess programs all using the same GUI. So in terms of graphics and probably the menu options all their chess programs look the same.

However, when it comes to features such as analysis or training, does Fritz 17 have anything special over other programs such as Komodo 14? Can it produce better quality commentaries or more meaningful probes to the opening books to make analysis more human like?

There are several similar questions here but they only deal with user interface rather than specifically analysis and training.

Comment: If you don't care much about the strength of the engine and just want some software to help you with training, ChessBase is the product you're looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fritz 17 is really just the same Chessbase GUI bundled with a chess engine Fritz 17. Depend on what version you buy, your Chessbase product may come with MegaDatabase - a huge collection of master chess games. Fritz 17 doesn't give you that.

EDITED:

Fritz 17 is not a public chess engine in the sense that it only works for Chessbase. I'm not aware it runs on anything other than Chessbase GUI. But it's actually an advantage. The engine is able to offer things that a standard engine like Komodo can't do. A standard engine must comply with the UCI chess protocol, whereas a private engine bundled with GUI can do anything. The last time when I used Fritz, I remember it offered GUI advice not available in UCI protocol. I don't use it anymore because it doesn't run on Mac.

Komodo engine has skill levels.

Comment: Well, I ask since some features might need special support in the Engine. For example Fritz 17 has "rated game" feature in the classic menu where you can set the ELO rating the of computer opponent. I wonder if all such features work identically say in Komodo 14?

Comment: @AlefSin EDITED

Answer (score 0):

I would say even if you buy Komodo, you will still need to use a GUI for it, so it will be very similar except for the engine you have,

on the side note, for analyzing games, Fritz has an option that I haven't see on Chessbase program and it's "compare analysis", so let say you have komod, fritz and stockfish, you can have them all look at your game and sometimes they have different plan, moves and even slightly different evaluation, which could be fun.